# Is there a difference between "note-taking" & "notation"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Is there a difference between "note-taking" & "notation" when referring to the process of writing notes? I've read the dictionary definitions and I'm still not clear on it.

Comment: Yes, a big difference. _Note-taking/Taking notes_ is just, well, writing down notes -- an activity. _Notation_, on the other hand, is an abstract system of signs, like [mathematical notation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-MathematicalNotation.pdf) or [logical notation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-LogicalNotation.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler It seems like the terms are often used interchangeably though.

Comment: My guess would be that speakers who've only heard them pronounced with some non-English accents might well confuse them. But I've never seen them confused in writing. On the other hand, I'm a native American speaker.

Comment: What @JohnLawler said. The (uncommon) verb *notate* does, like the verb *note* mean to write something down. So there is a sense in which *notation* can refer to writing something down. But when people use the word *notation* they typically mean a particular system or convention of writing (see JL's comment).

Comment: @JohnLawler, by native American speaker, what do you mean by American? Are you using it like Hemingway, who has a character say "I speak American" (as opposed to English)?

Comment: I am a native speaker of Midwestern American English. I also speak a native American language ([Lushootseed](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Lushootseed.html)), though not very well, and certainly not often.

Comment: @John: Perhaps influenced by the [Tower of Babel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Babel) myth, I'm firmly in the *"Universal language? Bring it on!"* camp. Also perhaps influenced by the fact that since Esperanto clearly isn't going anywhere, I already speak the hot favourite for the role. But looking at your link (and especially, [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lushootseed_language)) reminds me why it's worth hanging on to languages (even when sometimes no-one wants them to be the "mother tongue" of their offspring).

Comment: @FF: Yes, I've always felt that Lushootseed (I learned the Skagit dialect, so that's what I call it) gives one a very different perspective on how people can think and talk. And my students tended to think so, too, once they'd sweated the details out on those problems.

Comment: @John I've always wanted to (somehow or other) learn a Salish language… but my tongue and pharynx tend to hurt after trying to pronounce about five words, so I've never gotten very far. I don't think my vocal tract was made to distinguish ingressive, ejective, pharyngealised, affricated consonant clusters in five post-velar places of articulation.

Comment: That's why it was ideal for field methods class. We had enough time to practice and figure stuff out. It took me quite a while to learn to say the word for vine maple (_Acer circinatum_), my favorite NW tree: /t̉qt̉qʔats/. The stress is on the /a/.

Answer (score 2):

This question borders on general reference, I think, except that (1) *note-taking* doesn't show up in many dictionaries, and (2) both *note* and *notation* have multiple definitions to wade through, and some of those definitions overlap. First, let's look at the definition of *note-taking* in Merriam-Webster's *Third New International Dictionary* (1986):

> **note-taking** *n* the act or process of taking notes

Here it seems probable that the "notes" in question involve one or the other of the following meanings of *note* (from the same source):

> **note** *n* ... **3 b** (1) **:** a brief writing intended to assist the memory or to serve s the basis for a fuller statement . MINUTE : MEMORANDUM {made a *note* on a piece of paper —Barnaby Conrad} (2) **:** a condensed record of a speech, lecture, lesson, or discussion made at the time made at the time of listening {takes extensive *notes* in all his classes}

In contrast, *notation* in many instances refers to "a system of characters, symbols, or abbreviated expressions" or to the act, process, [or] method of representing" in such a system (again I'm quoting from MW's TNID).

What complicates this seemingly straightforward picture is that *notation* can also mean something very much like *note* definition 3b(1) or 3b(2). The relevant TNID definitions:

> **notation** *n* ... **2 a :** ANNOTATION, NOTE {damage, according to the constable's *notations*, consisted of broken front bumper —Richard Joseph} {if a letter refers to an enclosure, add the appropriate *notation* to the closing lines —D.D. Lessenberry & T.J. Crawford} **b :** an act of noting : OBSERVATION ... **5** The act or an instance of recording (as natural appearances or states of mind) through artistic or literary means ... {the whole purport of literature ... is the *notation* of the heart —Thornton Wilder}

It follows that, in actual practice, "note-taking" and "making notations" can sometimes be very difficult acts or processes to tell apart.